# How to add custom notification type to jira

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I have a problem in adding custom "Notification Type" (second column visible on page - http://host:port/secure/admin/AddNotification!default.jspa). I am using jira 4.2 and I found out that the interface that is responsible for this task in Jira is http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/4.2/com/atlassian/jira/notification/NotificationType.html, however I have no idea what to do next. Any help please :)

Comment: https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JCWP/JIRA+Component+Watcher+Plugin adds a new notification type, should have some helpful code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution is to Extend class AbstractNotificationType - extended class ex. MyNotificationType
and then create another class like the code below:

```
    public MyNotificationUpdater() {

    NotificationTypeManager notificationTypeManager = ComponentManager
            .getComponentInstanceOfType(NotificationTypeManager.class);
    Map types = notificationTypeManager.getTypes();
    if (types == null) {            
        types = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    types.put("MyNotificationType", new MyNotificationType());
    notificationTypeManager.setSchemeTypes(types);      
}
```